# Изменить timestamp на указанное количество секунд

Tags: mysql, sql, дата, timestamp

Есть условная таблица пользователей: `login, password, ...., created_at`

Как передвинуть дату регистрации (`created_at`) всех пользователей? Скажем, на 1000 секунд вперед или 10000 секунд назад. Дата хранится в `timestamp`.

Comment: Использовать UPDATE с соотв. выражением. Типа `SET created_at = created_at + INTERVAL 1000 SECOND`.

Answer (score 1):

Для работы с датами в `SQL` есть `INTERVAL`. Типы данных от секунды до года.
Чтобы запрос работал правильно:

```
SELECT created_at + INTERVAL 1000 SECOND AS created_at FROM your_table WHERE conditions;
```

Если хотите обновить данные, используйте аналогичный запрос для `UPDATE`.
Вот ссылка для ознакомления http://code.mu/sql/interval.html.